# autoconfigure not tagging commands with symfony dependency-injection

Tags: symfony

I have a cli project that I am using Symfony's Dependency Injection and Console components. I am **not** using a Kernel, controllers, etc.

When using `autoconfigure: true`, the service doesn't get the `console.command` tag it is supposed to.

My composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "monolog/monolog": "^2.0",
    "symfony/console": "^5.0",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.0",
    "symfony/config": "^5.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^5.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Mudder\\": "src/"}
  }
}
```

./config/services.yaml:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  Mudder\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    public: true
```

./src/Mudder/Command/HelloWorld.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mudder\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HelloWorld extends Command
{
    protected static string $defaultName = 'test';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setDescription('Foo');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Hello, world.');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally, ./test.php (the cli entrypoint):

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader($containerBuilder, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/config'));
$loader->load('services.yaml');
$containerBuilder->compile();

print_r($containerBuilder->getDefinition(\Mudder\Command\HelloWorld::class)->getTags());
```

Output from the print_r() is an empty array "Array()"

Comment: The container itself knows nothing about console commands.  The FrameworkBundle extension provides the mappings.  You can take a look there to see what you will need to add to container builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container itself does know nothing about a Command.

If you want to auto configure your commands, you have to call

```php
$containerBuiler->registerForAutoconfiguration(Command::class)->addTag('console.command');
```

or load the FrameworkExtension (from symfony FrameworkBundle)

Comment: Thank you Alessandro! I guess this is where the documentation had me scratching my head. It kind of goes back and forth from "this works while using Symfony kernel" to "this is how it works stand-alone".

Answer (score 0):

Your command should end with **Command**. Rename it to **HelloWorldCommand**.

Comment: Yeah that appears to be best practice, so I changed it. However does not fix the issue stated.